Error when deploying smart-contract on testnet with blueprint
I started studying TON development, wrote a contract based on a video tutorial
when deploying the contract it gives the following error:

npx blueprint run
Using file: deployCounter
? Which network do you want to use? testnet
Error: no healthy nodes for v4-testnet
at Access.buildUrls

I haven't found any information about solving this problem anywhere.
Help me pls...

I also just started studying and about 5 minutes ago I meet the same problem
And I found out that perhaps these were temporary interruptions that would pass later. You can view the network status here: https://ton-access-status.herokuapp.com/
Not entirely sure about all of this, but it seems to be true.

wow, thank you, I didn’t even think that there might be problems with the network
